# Observable property not initialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

When I try to use my Mobx stores the observables are not there, not initialized. For example:

**AStore.js**

```
class A {
  @observable prop1 = ''
}
```

**App.js**

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.store = new A()
  }
}
```

When I `console.log(this.store)` its an empty object. I've used Mobx before and have always declared my `@observables` like in `class A`, in fact, I'm literally copying a previous project I used Mobx.

Comment: May be because you type "contractor" instead of "constructor"? )

Comment: @vovkasm that was just a typo, thank you for pointing it out lol

Comment: This looks pretty ok, I make a quick test... https://jsfiddle.net/owtyrm65/